# Proof by induction that $3^{n+1} > n^4$

Tags: induction

> Prove $3^{n+1} > n^4$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $n \neq 3, n \neq 4$.

Let P(n) be the statement "$3^{n+1} > n^4$ such that $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $n \neq 3, n \neq 4$."

I have proved the base cases, P(1), P(2), P(5), but I got stuck on the inductive step.

I said: Let $k \in \mathbb{N}, k \geq 5$, assume P(k) is true.
Show P(k+1) is true.

$P(k+1) = 3^{k+2} > (k+1)^4 $

I got stuck here and don't know how to proceed, any help is greatly appreaciated!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: given $P(k)$, that is, $3^{k+1} > k^4$, you want to show $P(k+1)$, which is

$$3^{k+2} > (k+1)^4$$

You might try

$$3^{k+2} = 3 \times 3^{k+1} > 3 k^4\ \ \ \ \text{(induction hypothesis)}$$

and see if this is bigger than $(k+1)^4$.

Comment: Ah ok thanks, that makes sense.

Comment: Who down voted this and why?  @JohnMa I cannot tolerate these anonymous down voters and have given a +1 to neutralize.  Your HINT is solid!

Comment: Thanks @Dr.MV , the downvoter might just follow the advise here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21290/can-i-try-to-tell-experienced-users-not-to-answer-bad-questions (which I think is quite nonsense)

Comment: @JohnMa Yes, I agree with you.  Why would answering any posted question be considered "punishable."  I thought we are trying to help one another, not apply pressure to "not answer."  I rarely ever down vote.  Rather, I will leave a comment for an answer that is hopefully constructive.  Best wishes!  ;-))